# Measuring font fontsize of CTabItems in SWT?

Tags: java, swt, font-size, ctabitem

I have got some CTab items, which I want to measure, especially I need to know the actual Font Size, so that if I change the Tab Size - I do not won't set it smaller, than the font-size.

How can I measure the fontsize of CTabItems in SWT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
item.getFont().getFontData()[0].getHeight()
```

will give you the font size used in the `item`.